# Syntax Error: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, npm-publish

I am unable to use my npm component package that i have created.
I have published the package successfully but when i am using it in a fresh code it is showing this error "SyntaxError: /home/trinendra/Desktop/react-test/node_modules/iconbox1/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (6:17)"

My package name:"iconbox1"

**My npm package code is here:**

```
import React,{Component} from "react"

class Welcome extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your name"></input>
        )
    }
}

module.exports.Welcome = Welcome;
```

And i am using it here in my main app:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {Welcome} from "iconbox1"


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Welcome></Welcome>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ifqp.png)

Comment: can you share the package.json of your package.

Answer (score 0):

Might be good not to mix ES5 and ES6. This might be happening because of the way you are exporting your Component.

- There is a render(){} function missing in your App component.
- Try exporting Your welcome component using export {Welcome} or export default Welcome, but make sure to remove the brackets around welcome in your app component if you are using the second option

Comment: you don't need render method in functional components.

Comment: I have done the changes but still it is giving the same error

Comment: Try changing the welcome component to <Welcome /> rather than <Welcome></Welcome>

Answer (score 0):

You are using both ES6 and ES5 syntax for importing and exporting.

Try this code instead [Here's a Screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0y2I.png). It's working for me

Check the name of the file is iconbox1 or not

```
import React,{Component} from "react"

class Welcome extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your name"></input>
        )
    }
}

export default Welcome;
```

```
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Welcome from "./iconbox1"


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Welcome></Welcome>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I have done the changes but still it is giving the same error